# Iteration issue when coding for Turtle module

Tags: loops, iteration, turtle-graphics

I keep getting an error message that 'i' is an unused variable, but I'm using it to iterate a loop that has a variable range depending on user input (numShapes). Why is python not accepting that variable when it is an integer value?

***This code is meant to call one of two drawing functions for the turtle module, randomly placing a variable amount (numShapes) of drawings of varying sizes and places within the bounds.

```
import random
import turtle, BoundingBox
from TurtleShapes import drawOneSquare
from TurtleShapes import drawOneShape

x = turtle.Turtle()

def drawEverywhere(x, func):      
    numShapes = int(input("How many shapes?"))
    for i in range(numShapes):
        x.penup()
        x.goto((random.randint(-1150,1150), random.randint(-550,550))      

        for i in range(numShapes):
            func(turtle, size))
                size = random.randint(10,40)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win = turtle.Screen()
    BoundingBox.drawBoundingBox()

    ### Decide which shape ###
    input("Which shape? 's' for square or 'c' for circle")
        if input == 's':
            drawEverywhere(turtle, drawOneSquare)
        elif input == 'c':    
            drawEverywhere(turtle, drawOneShape)   
        else:
            print('invalid input') 

    win.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we have a loop like:

```
for i in range(10):
    print(":-)")
```

Some Python code checkers will flag the variable `i` as unused as it's set but its value is never used.  A common way around this is to use Python's general purpose "throwaway" variable name `_` instead:

```
for _ in range(10):
    print(":-)")
```

See if that suppresses the *unused* warning you've been getting.  This is one of several uses of the `_` variable in Python.

Other notes about your code:

```
x.goto((random.randint(-1150,1150), random.randint(-550,550))
```

It's missing a closing parenthesis and doesn't require the extra opening parenthesis to make a tuple -- it can simplify to:

```
from random import randint
# ...
x.goto(randint(-1150, 1150), randint(-550, 550))
```

This code will give you trouble:

```
func(turtle, size))
    size = random.randint(10,40)
```

Due to the unbalanced parenthesis, unjustified indentation and order of execution.  You probably want:

```
size = random.randint(10, 40)
func(turtle, size)
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm not getting an invalid syntax error message for ` size = random.randint(10,40) ` do you have any idea why this might be?

Comment: @SydneyBallard, if you did the `from random import randint` I mentioned, then the syntax would be `size = randint(10, 40)`.  Otherwise, I don't see a reason for a syntax error and you might open a new question with your current, complete code.